# Defined behaviour for union with 24-bit and 8-bit vars

Tags: c++, unions, bit-fields

I'm trying to find the best way to pack a 24-bit and 8-bit unsigned integer together into 32 bits without requiring bit-shifts to extract data. Unions immediately came to mind with a simple approach looking like this:

```
union {
    uint32_t u24;
    uint8_t u8[4]; // use only u8[3]
}
```

However, this approach results in undefined behavior based on a system's endianness, so I came up with the following approach that uses a c++20 feature to detect a system's endianness at compile time using std::endian and constexpr:

```
#include <bit>
struct UnionTest {
    union {
        uint32_t u24;
        uint8_t u8[4];
    };
    
    inline constexpr uint8_t get_u8_index() const noexcept {
        if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::little) return 0;
        else if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::big) return 3;
        else // crap the bed
    }
};

// use like this:
int main() {
    UnionTest test;
    test.u24 = 0xffffff;
    test.u8[test.get_u8_index()] = 0xff;
}
```

This may be a bit verbose still, but that's not the issue. I am purely interested in the viability of this approach, assuming we never write values larger than 24 bits into u24.

A different way would be to use bit-fields:

```
struct UnionTest {
    uint32_t u24 : 24;
    uint32_t u8 : 8;
}
```

But this may result in 64 bits rather than 32 (even though it should be expected to be 32 in most cases).

My question would be A) about the feasibility of the union approach regarding performance and potentially undefined behavior and B) the actual difference between the proposed union approach and the usage of c++ bit-fields

Comment: Endianness isn't the only problem with a union like that. In C++ you may *only* read from the member that was last written to. You're not allowed type-punning through unions in C++.

Comment: As for the bit-field, it's also troublesome as the compiler might put the two members in any order it pleases, there's no well-defined order of members sharing bits.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Meaning that I would end up being forced to simply use a single 32-bit value and pack/extract using bit-shifts as per usual? Or is there a compile-time-constant approach for it?

Comment: Unfortunately that's still the safest and most portable way to handle it.

Comment: @JanKuhlmann What exactly is the problem with bit-shifts? You only need to type them out once in accessor member functions.

Comment: @user17732522 They work perfectly fine, I was just interested in whether there was a constexpr approach to do it. Partially for readability and partially for performance, whereas the latter would most likely be negligible at best.

Comment: As you only need a single byte and everything but that byte, you could use the fact that C++ allows to examine and set the byte representation of an object. You would immediately get a direct access to the byte, and just a mask the read the 24 bit value, and save and reset the byte to write the 24 bits value...

Comment: @SergeBallesta That sounds both fun and cursed, how would I "examine and set the byte representation" of an object? This is just for myself, I won't cause any colleagues suffering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ language allows to access the byte representation on any object. It is explicitely used to allow byte copy of trivially copyable types. Furthermore, if endianness is defined, you can expect a 24 bits value to use the 3 high order bytes for little endian and the 3 low order bytes for big endian. A mask it still required to access the 24 bits value, but the 8 bits one can be accessed directly, and no shift is ever used.

Here is an possible code demonstrating that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bit>

namespace {
    inline constexpr uint8_t get_u8_index() noexcept {
        if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::little) return 3;
        else if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::big) return 0;
        else {}// crap the bed
    }
}

class pack_24_8 {
    uint32_t value;

    static const int u8_index = get_u8_index();  // locally scoped constant

public:
    uint8_t get_u8() const {
        return ((const uint8_t*)(&value))[u8_index]; // extract one single byte
    }

    void set_u8(uint8_t c) {
        ((uint8_t*)(&value))[u8_index] = c;  // set one single byte
    }

    uint32_t get_u24() const {
        return value & 0xffffff;      // get the less significant 24 bits
    }

    void set_u24(uint32_t u24) {
        uint8_t u8 = get_u8();    // save the u8 part
        value = u24;
        set_u8(u8);               // and restore it
    }
};

// use like this:
int main() {
    pack_24_8 test;
    test.set_u8(0x5a);
    test.set_u24(0xa5a5a5);

    std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned int) test.get_u8() << " - " <<
        std::hex << test.get_u24() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Beware: as said by @Caleth in comment, this relies on `uint8_t` being an alias for unsigned char. AFAIK this is true for every common architecture, but it is not required per standard...

Comment: That's a pretty nice solution, especially if you only access part of the 32 bits frequently, in this case the 8 bits. Taught me about anonymous namespaces as well, have not seen those before!

Comment: This is relying on `uint8_t` being an alias for `unsigned char` to have defined behaviour

Comment: @Caleth: you are certainly right. I am so used to that that I did not imagine it could be different... I've edited my post with your remark.